# JQuery-UI and jQuery-DataTable compatibility with Lightning Locker Service

Tags: lightning-aura-components, jquery, lightning, locker-service

Is there any version of following libraries:

- jQuery-UI (https://jqueryui.com/)
- jquery-DataTable (https://datatables.net/)
- Bootstrap JS (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)

That are compatible with Locker Service?

When using `.autocomplete()` function from jQuery-UI I'm getting following error:

```
Something has gone wrong. afterRender threw an error in 'markup://aura:html' 
[afterRender threw an error in 'markup://aura:html' 
[afterRender threw an error in 'markup://aura:html' 
[afterRender threw an error in 'markup://aura:html' 
[afterRender threw an error in 'markup://aura:html' 
[afterRender threw an error in 'markup://c:CPQ_UTIL01_Autocomplete'
[TypeError: Cannot define property:jQuery224091732131111102392, object is not extensible.]]]]]] 
Failing descriptor: {markup://aura:html}. Please try again.
```

Also `.tooltip()` function from Bootstrap is not working for me.

I'm trying to bring back some functionalities that are built on these libraries.

Case is already opened: #14139006

Comment: Where in Salesforce am I supposed to file a Case? I'm fairly new to the ecosystem and I'm not sure which queue the devs actually look at...

Answer (score 2):

Actually for jQuery-UI it seems to be working, the issue was of different nature:

In the original scenario I had:

```
<ui:inputText aura:id="autocomplete" ...>
```

And I was trying to do:

```
$(autocomplete).autocomplete({
   ...
});
```

It seems that secure DOM introduced by locker service very effectively forces ownership of DOM elements, and I was not able to put autocomplete function on a different component (`ui:inputText`)

After changing the view to standard:

```
<input type="text" ... >
```

All seems to be working.

Comment: Can you let me know what version of jQueryUI are using ? I was facing a similar problem with datepciker and I have raised a case with  sf and its been considered as a bug

Comment: I'm using current stable version: v1.11.4